# How to backup/restore under a different db name with pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-dump

Using pg_dump under an AWS EC2, I want to make a copy of an existing database but under a new database name, potentially on a different instance.

I tried something like this

```
pg_dump -C --no-owner --no-tablespaces --dbname=eric --host=fs-......eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=sa --password | psql -h fs-...SameOrOtherName.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=sa --password --dbname=new_eric
```

This comes back with the error

> "psql: FATAL: database "new_eric" does not exist"

I am trying to avoid generating a pg_dump file, then modifying it, then reloading it...

I suppose I could "sed" to replace some stuff on the fly...?

Comment: made some progress (?) by using both -c and -C options together

`pg_dump -C -c --no-owner --no-tablespaces --dbname=eric --host=fs-......eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=sa --password | 
psql -h fs-...SameOrOtherName.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=sa --password --dbname=new_eric`

but I get various output and error messages that don't seem normal...

Comment: suspicious output...

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config
------------

(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  database "eric" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 2 other sessions using the database.
ERROR:  database "eric" already exists